# Property weaker than continuity

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map between matric spaces. I'm interested in the following property:

> For every $x\in X$, there is a sequence $x_n\to x$, with $x_n\ne x$ for every $n$, such that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Question: What's known about functions with this property? Does some well studied class of functions have it?

Clearly every continuous function has the property above (if the space has no isolated points), but it can be violated by changing the value of the continuous function in one single point. On the other hand, sharply discontinuous functions can have the property, as for instance the Dirichlet function or even Conway base-13 function.

Thanks.

Comment: A funny property to consider... :)

Comment: Yeah, but for what I want to do (working with $\epsilon$-chains) it's a fairly natural property to ask.

Comment: I don't know about general metric space considerations, but given that your "pathological examples" are simply real-valued functions defined on the reals, I think you should begin with this before trying to generalize to metric spaces. And if you do generalize, perhaps begin with complete separable metric spaces, then consider complete non-separable metric spaces, then $\ldots$ Probably much that will be useful can be found in [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/231462/15780). Also [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309019/15780).

Comment: "Trying-to-be-sequentially-continuous functions"? :)

Comment: Conidtion fails at all isolated points! So different from ordinary continuity!

Comment: I wrote it indeed.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks, all very interesting stuff... but as far as I can see those results concern whether there exists just one point with the given property, while I'm interested in conditions ensuring that it holds at every point, or for instance on a co-countable or even co-meagre set.